# "The package system is broken" due to VLC dependency errors

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, vlc

> The package system is broken
>
> Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
>   Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> ```
> libvlccore8: Depends: vlc-data (= 2.2.5.1~ppa) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180121+r73720+120~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed
>              Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is installed
> vlc: Depends: vlc-bin (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180121+r73720+120~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not installed
>      Depends: vlc-plugin-base (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180121+r73720+120~ubuntu16.04.1) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180121+r73720+120~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed
>      Depends: vlc-plugin-qt (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180121+r73720+120~ubuntu16.04.1) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180121+r73720+120~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed
>      Depends: vlc-plugin-video-output (= 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180121+r73720+120~ubuntu16.04.1) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180121+r73720+120~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed
> ```

I cannot update or install anything. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: are you using a PPA for VLC? Looks like it is causing a bad conflict and should be disabled in software & updates settings?

Comment: Yes your assumption is right. I am using PPA for VLC and I also disabled it in software & update setting but know it showing error : Failed to download repository information

Comment: in that case, please open a terminal and run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install -f` and (if that doesn't fix it) copy and paste the full output of both commands into your question, and format it as code by highlighting it and pressing ctrl+k or clicking the `{}` button